# My website showing only html view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cross-browser

I developed a website in CodeIgniter. In it, i saved all my CSS and js files outside of the application folder and I included them using URL helper base_url and site_url. But even I can see those file being loaded in the code view from the browser, I don't see any changes I see in the browser. I viewed the project in firefox and it is working even when I don't use the site_url function

Comment: Have you enabled caching in your codeigniter configuration ?

Comment: You couldn't use `site_url()` function since it'd return something like `http://example.com/index.php/styles.css` until you made some acrobatic code to parse CSS through controller which I doubt is case here. Maybe problem with browser cache? Close all browsers and try in new private browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the description of the problem is not very accurate i think, but please try the following.

Your .htaccess

```
options -indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)

#LOCALHOST , ARVIXE , HOSTGATOR ETC.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#GODADDY 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1  [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Your application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project'; //the url where your project is
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Your application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url'); //at least 'url', but i recommennd 'array', 'file'
```

I think that may resolve the problem.If it doesnt, please provide further details.

Let me know,

Comment: I used the .htaccess file given in the user guide of CodeIgniter, and I also set the base URL, removed the index page name and autoloaded the URL helper. But for some reason, it is working now. But thank you anyways